# How to make this field mutable?

Tags: struct, rust, mutability

I'm stuck here for some time now and cannot figure out how to make the field `word` mutable. Can somebody please point me out the issue here.

```
pub struct Person<'name>{
    name:&'name Name
}

pub struct Name{
     word: String
}

impl<'name> Person<'name>{
    pub fn new(name:&'name mut Name)-> Person<'name>{
        Person {
            name: name
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut name: Name = Name {
        word: String::from("Petre")
    };
    let mut person: Person = Person::new(&mut name);
    first(&mut person);

}

pub fn first(person:&mut Person){
    person.name.word = String::from("Wurst");
    second(person);
}

pub fn second(person:&mut Person){
    println!("{}",person.name.word)
}
```

**Output**

> ```
> error: cannot assign to immutable field `person.name.word`
>   --> main.rs:27:5
>    |
> 27 |     person.name.word = String::from("Wurst");
>    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: It's not mutable because you specifically said that it shouldn't be mutable.  Is there some reason you can't just use `&'name mut Name`?  **Edit**: also, you don't make fields mutable; a field is mutable or not depending on how you reach it, and in this case, you reach it via `Person.name`, which is an immutable pointer.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at your `Person` struct:

```
pub struct Person<'name>{
    name:&'name Name
}
```

The `name` field is an *immutable* reference, so you can't write through it.  Simply make it a mutable reference:

```
pub struct Person<'name>{
    name:&'name mut Name
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=be4b757bd880d46f2ec2b7aff5b9a187&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Answer (score 2):

By marking the field as a mutable reference:

```
pub struct Person<'name>{
    name:&'name mut Name
} //            ^^^ mutable
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=64501a5c02e7caa05c183ff3afc0818f&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 1):

I think you expected `person.name` to be mutable due to the way you implemented the `new()` method for `Person`, where the `name` argument is a mutable reference to a `Name` struct:

```
fn new(name: &'name mut Name)
```

But this only means the function argument needs to be one - it doesn't result in the fact that the target `Person`'s field can be mutated. You can pass a mutable reference to a target expecting an immutable reference, but you can't do it the other way round; you would get a `values differ in mutability` error.

As the others correctly pointed out, the field needs to be explicitly marked as `mut`able in order to allow its mutability:

```
struct Person<'name>{
    name: &'name mut Name
}
```